# Aliasing type of incomplete template of template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, clang

I have been struggling with this for a couple days. I am porting some code to MacOS/AppleClang and we have very heavy templated code that builds correctly on MSVC but fails on clang (understandably, because, after reading around, our code is not up to the standard). But I really can't find a way to do this properly.

Here is the original code, that builds and works fine on MSVC:

```
template<typename ValueType>
class MemoryDataLayout
{
  //Do stuff;
};

template<typename LayoutType = MemoryDataLayout>
class MemoryBufferView
{
public:
  using this_container = MemoryBufferView<LayoutType>;
  using layout_type = LayoutType;
  //Do stuff;
};
```

Does not compile because Clang cannot find the `MemoryDataLayout` type.

But if I write it our like this:

```
template<template <typename Type> class LayoutType = MemoryDataLayout>
class MemoryBufferView
{
public:
  using this_container = MemoryBufferView<LayoutType>;
  using layout_type = LayoutType;
  //Do stuff;
};
```

The compiler understandably complains about `using layout_type = LayoutType;`

Ideally, I know I should be writing `using layout_type = LayoutType<Type>;`, but it seems Type is not visible from this context.

I know I could probably write it out like this:

```
template<typename Type, template <typename> class LayoutType = MemoryDataLayout>
class MemoryBufferView
{
public:
  using this_container = MemoryBufferView<LayoutType>;
  using layout_type = LayoutType<Type>;
  //Do stuff;
};
```

But this would mean changing a lot of code throughout the codebase, so if I can keep it "compatible" with just the one template argument it would be ideal... if at all possible.

Oh, and we are limited to C++17, nothing newer, unfortunately.

I am out of ideas for now so any help would be appreciated.

**[EDIT for more details]**

The way this classe is instantiated in the codebase, with the default layout, is `MemoryBufferView<char> m;`

The only close solution I found to keep most of the codebase compliant is the following:

```
template<typename ValueType>
class MemoryDataLayout
{
//Do stuff;
};

template<typename T, template<typename> class LayoutType = MemoryDataLayout>
class MemoryBufferView
{
public:
  using this_container = MemoryBufferView<T, LayoutType>;
  using layout_type = LayoutType<T>;
//Do stuff;
};

void f(){
    MemoryBufferView<char> m;
}
```

But this only works when calling MemoryBufferView with the default layout (otherwise I have to change the calls).

I could live with that, but for curiosity's sake, if there is anything better, I would be happy to read it :)

**[FINAL EDIT]**

I ended up using the solution I proposed above, it's cleaner and more accurate to what we want going on.

Comment: MemoryDataLayout is a template, not a type. Period. user:11638718 answers should do the job (though it lacks explainations) if you don't want to change your design (which might be understandable).

Comment: What is `MemoryBufferView<char>` meant to be? what operations do `char` and `MemoryDataLayout<T>` share?

Comment: Do you ever instantiate this template with the default template parameter? MSVC rejects [this](https://godbolt.org/z/exr7Pjq7s)

Comment: `MemoryBufferView<char>` is supposed to be MemoryBufferView<MemoryDataLayout<char>>`
I would like to stress that this horror is not my code, and I am just trying to bring it up to norm :)

Comment: "if I can keep it "compatible" with just the one template argument" `template<typename Type, template <typename> class LayoutType = MemoryDataLayout> class MemoryBufferView` *is* compatible with one template argument. Your original template isn't compatible with zero arguments

Comment: In your current msvc codebase, `MemoryBufferView<char> m;` does not use `MemoryDataLayout`

Comment: Well it actually does not work with zero arguments (which is no surprise).

I guess I will be using my own 2 arguments solution. It's clean and proper.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't match your description of your system. does `// do stuff` have mentions of `MemoryDataLayout`?

Comment: When writing code in MSVC which should be accepted ISO-compatible compilers, make sure that you don't have `/permissive-` flag set. It disables a number of valid syntaxes while there are few things, like deferred code parsing in templates, which is historically a non-alienable feature. It also enables some ISO-incompatible declarations or defines, e.g. `__cplusplus` in that mode is always 1, `std::move` and some other behavior changes (intrinstic inlining happens), etc. Behaviour in that mode often differes from one minor version of compiler to another.

Answer (score 3):

Your current code isn't ever using the default for that template parameter. MSVC is slightly non-compliant, in that it defers some checking of templates to instantiation time. `MemoryBufferView<char>` does not use the default template parameter, it is entirely replaced by `char`. You seem to have a misunderstanding of what is going on in your code if you think `MemoryDataLayout` affects `MemoryBufferView<char>`.

The least impactful change you can make is to remove the incorrect default parameter:

```
template<typename LayoutType>
class MemoryBufferView
{
public:
  using this_container = MemoryBufferView<LayoutType>;
  using layout_type = LayoutType;
  //Do stuff;
};
```

Clang [will accept it](https://godbolt.org/z/r7jMG5v5K), and you aren't changing the behaviour of your existing code.

Comment: MSVC v.15.x  is also full of regressions and  deflects perfectly valid code. One also should watch out for `/permissive-` "Conformance" flag, which is set default. De-facto it's opposite of Conformance, because compiler starts to behave in non-ISO compliant way.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `layout_type` an alias template

```
template<template <typename Type> class LayoutType = MemoryDataLayout>
class MemoryBufferView
{
public:
  using this_container = MemoryBufferView<LayoutType>;
  template<typename ValueType>
  using layout_type = LayoutType<ValueType>;
  //Do stuff;
};
```

Comment: How would you pass the `ValueType` type in this case? it should be the same as `Type`. I quickly tried it, but it doesn't even compile, sorry to say ':-)

I edited my question for more details on the expected outcome.

Comment: @LarrxX neither `Type` nor `ValueType` are types, they are both unbound template parameters. It's somewhat unfortunate that you can even give `Type` a name.

Comment: but how would you instantiatie `ValueType` in your example?

Comment: @LarrxX If I understand correctly, it seems that you only need to change the default template  parameter of the `MemoryBufferView` to `MemoryDataLayout<char>` i.e. https://godbolt.org/z/1hq93nfbe.

Comment: or just removing the default template value actually. Because using zero arguments does not work and is definitely not supposed to work.

However, I prefer to use the solution I posted myself, since it is closer to the original intent of the developer.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename ValueType>
class MemoryDataLayout
{
//Do stuff;
};

template<typename T, template<typename> class LayoutType = MemoryDataLayout>
class MemoryBufferView
{
public:
  using this_container = MemoryBufferView<T, LayoutType>;
  using layout_type = LayoutType<T>;
//Do stuff;
};

void f(){
    MemoryBufferView<char> m;
}
```

I ended up using this approach, that is more correct and actually does what the original developer intended. Thanks all for your help and input.